# Multiple file upload with Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I already program ajax multiple file upload form but it is not working properly.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" id="postfrom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" multiple accept=".mp4, .mov, .m4v, .MPEG-4, .gif, .jpg, .png"/>
</form>

<button type="button" class="btnb btnb-primary" id="submitpost"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitpost", function(){
    $("#postfrom").submit();
});


$("#postfrom").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         url : "/php/post_submit.php",
         type: "POST",
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         data : new FormData(this),
         success: function(response){
            $('.result').html(response);
            alert(response);

         },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

How to solve this error. I get nothing from PHP response.

Comment: Do you get any response without jquery code?

Comment: Nope. I get only "array()" response.